# Sending message from Application-Server to target application on Android device

Tags: url

**How to know exactly what URL does the 3rd-party application-server try to access while sending message to a client-device via the GCM-server?**

In "SendAllMessagesServlet.java" 
(which can be found @ android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java)

```
.....
// Error 500 ( Connection timed out) at the following line    

Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
.....
```

3rd-party app-server - Tomcat v7.0

Answer (score 0):

The URL is in the Constants.java file as GCM_SEND_ENDPOINT
in the android\gcm\gcm-server libray

public static final String GCM_SEND_ENDPOINT =
      "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

The error 500 is due to proxy settings.

Thank You